# Docker-compose volume mount before run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile I'm pointing at from a docker-compose.yml.

I'd like the volume mount in the docker-compose.yml to happen before the `RUN` in the Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli \
 && npm install

ENTRYPOINT gulp watch
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  build_tools:
    build: docker/gulp
    volumes_from:
      - build_data:rw

  build_data:
    image: debian:jessie
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

It makes complete sense for it to do the Dockerfile first, then mount from docker-compose, however is there a way to get around it.

I want to keep the Dockerfile generic, while passing more specific bits in from compose. Perhaps that's not the best practice?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[Erik Dannenberg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089784/827081) is correct, the volume layering means that what I was trying to do makes no sense. (There is another really good explaination on the [Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/) if you want to read more). If I want to have Docker do the `npm install` then I could do it like this:

```dockerfile
FROM node

ADD . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli \
 && npm install

CMD ["gulp", "watch"]
```

However, this isn't appropriate as a solution for my situation. The goal is to use NPM to install project dependencies, then run gulp to build my project. This means I need read and write access to the project folder *and* it needs to persist after the container is gone.

---

I need to do two things after the volume is mounted, so I came up with the following solution...

docker/gulp/Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM node

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli

ADD start-gulp.sh .

CMD ./start-gulp.sh
```

docker/gulp/start-gulp.sh:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

until cd /usr/src/app && npm install
do
    echo "Retrying npm install"
done
gulp watch
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  build_tools:
    build: docker/gulp
    volumes_from:
      - build_data:rw

  build_data:
    image: debian:jessie
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

So now the container starts a bash script that will continuously loop until it can get into the directory *and* run `npm install`. This is still quite brittle, but it works. :)

Comment: T H A N K  Y O U  for this answer. I was trying to solve the same kind of problem with webpack. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058764/dockerized-django-with-webpackdevserver/41075389#41075389

Comment: you rock holmes! sweet answer

Answer (score 22):

You can't mount host folders or volumes during a Docker build. Allowing that would compromise build repeatability. The only way to access local data during a Docker build is the build context, which is everything in the `PATH` or `URL` you passed to the `build` command. Note that the `Dockerfile` needs to exist somewhere in context. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ for more details.

Comment: To clarify, per the reference, it would compromise build repeatability ^on remote docker hosts^.  If you're not doing that, I don't see how pre-arranging referenced files to be inside the docker build directory makes builds any more repeatable, but it means you need some external build mechanism.  Even docker-compose can't do it, so you need yet another build level.  More layers -> more complexity.  Silly.  Anyway, you can use https://github.com/CheggEng/dockerx if you want to be able to mount directories at build time, predefine build params, and not introduce a ton of other syntax to docker.