# Dockerized Django with webpackDevServer

Tags: django, docker, webpack, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need some help with a Docker configuration to make Django work with webpack dev server in development mode. I want django docker container to get access to the webpack generated bundle.

I'm struggling to understand how containers share files with volumes in docker-compose.

Until now I only managed to have a working django dockerized app and then I run npm install && node server.js locally.

**Dockerfile**

```
# use base python image with python 2.7
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set working directory to /code/
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# add requirements.txt to the image
ADD requirements.txt /code/

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /code/

# Port to expose
EXPOSE 8000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  redis:
    image: redis
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"  # we forward this port because it's useful for debugging
      - "15672:15672"  # here, we can access rabbitmq management plugin
  worker:
    build: .
    command: celery worker -A example -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./assets/bundles:/webpack (here I'm trying in some way to address webpack files to assets/bundles)
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
```

And this is my attempt with webpack

**Dockerfile.webpack**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /webpack
COPY package.json /webpack/
COPY server.js /webpack/

RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ && npm install

ADD . /webpack/

# Port to expose
EXPOSE 3000
```

this is the snippet added to docker-compose.yml

```
webpack:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.webpack
    command: node server.js
    volumes:
      - .:/webpack
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

**server.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var config = require('./webpack.config')

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  console.log('Listening at 0.0.0.0:3000')
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089162/docker-compose-volume-mount-before-run) I found the solution.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  webpack:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/webpack
    volumes_from:
      - webapp:rw

  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/webapp
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

**docker/webapp**

```
FROM python:latest
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set working directory to /code/
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# add requirements.txt to the image
ADD ./requirements.txt /code/

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /code/

# Port to expose
EXPOSE 8000
```

**docker/webpack**

```
from node:latest

RUN npm install webpack -g

ADD docker/start-webpack.sh .
RUN chmod +x /start-webpack.sh

CMD ./start-webpack.sh
```

**docker/start-webpack.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

until cd /code && npm install
do
  echo "Retrying npm install"
done

webpack --watch --watch-polling
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the `webpack-dev-server`, the actual outputs go to an [in-memory output filesystem](https://github.com/webpack/memory-fs), so the only way to access the bundle from Django would be to either provide clients with a URL to the public path where the bundle is returned by `webpack-dev-server`, or extend how the static assets are discovered and gathered to retrieve these over HTTP if only Django can access the Webpack container.

Now that that's covered, I'd recommend that you do not do it. Instead, use `webpack $ARGS` and `webpack --watch $DEV_ARGS`. This will write the outputs to the volume, which you can then share with Django.

Comment: I need some more help. I'm getting frustrated with it. What is the right way to write the output of a container (in this case webpack) to a volume that another container (in this case web) can access it form a directory (in this case ./code). It's all day that I'm trying to figure it out :/